# Footnote disappear in shaded environment

Tags: footnotes

My footnote disappear in shaded environment as shown in the following example. How to fix this, please? Thank you!

```
\documentclass[english]{scrartcl}

\usepackage{graphics}
\usepackage{environ}
\usepackage[round]{natbib}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{babel}
\setkomafont{disposition}{\normalfont\bfseries}
\usepackage[printwatermark]{xwatermark}
\usepackage[usenames,dvipsnames,svgnames,table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{framed}

\colorlet{shadecolor}{gray!40}

\begin{document}

\title{}
\maketitle

\begin{shaded}
\begin{enumerate}
\item I love my mother.\footnote{Of course.} 
\end{enumerate}
\end{shaded}

\end{document}
```

[image: Picture]

Answer (score 10, accepted):

From the `framed` manual:

> The contents of the framed regions are restricted: Floats, footnotes, margin-pars and head-line entries will be lost.

So, simply use `\footnotemark` inside the `shaded` environment and `\footnotetext{Of course.}` just after it.

MWE:

```
\documentclass[english]{scrartcl}

\usepackage{graphics}
\usepackage{environ}
\usepackage[round]{natbib}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{babel}
\setkomafont{disposition}{\normalfont\bfseries}
\usepackage[printwatermark]{xwatermark}
\usepackage[usenames,dvipsnames,svgnames,table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{framed}

\colorlet{shadecolor}{gray!40}

\begin{document}

\title{}
\maketitle

\begin{shaded}
\begin{enumerate}
\item I love my mother.\footnotemark
\end{enumerate}
\end{shaded}
\footnotetext{Of course.}

\end{document}
```

Output

[image]

---

### EDIT

If you have more than one footnote inside the `shaded` environment, then number your `\footnotetext`s, as in the following example:

```
\documentclass[english]{scrartcl}

\usepackage{graphics}
\usepackage{environ}
\usepackage[round]{natbib}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{babel}
\setkomafont{disposition}{\normalfont\bfseries}
\usepackage[printwatermark]{xwatermark}
\usepackage[usenames,dvipsnames,svgnames,table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{framed}

\colorlet{shadecolor}{gray!40}

\begin{document}

\title{}
\maketitle

\begin{shaded}
\begin{enumerate}
\item I love my mother.\footnotemark
\item And my father,too.\footnotemark
\end{enumerate}
\end{shaded}
\footnotetext[1]{Of course.}
\footnotetext[2]{Of course, again.}

And some text outside\footnote{A footnote}
\end{document}
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: Thank you. I forgot to ask what if I have more than one footnote?

Comment: @LaTeXfan See the edit

Answer (score 3):

Here's an automatic solution which supports `\footnote{<text>}` and `\footnote[<number>]{<text>}` used inside `shaded` environment, both with or without `hyperref`, nested in `minipage` environment or not.

Note by default `hyperref` doesn't support `\footnotetext[<number>]{<text>}`, see its package doc, sec. 12.3 "Footnotes".

```tex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{framed}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage[colorlinks]{hyperref}

\colorlet{shadecolor}{gray!40}

\makeatletter
\NewDocumentCommand \footnote@in@shaded { o m }{%
  \IfValueTF{#1}{%
    \begingroup
      \csname c@\@mpfn\endcsname #1\relax
      \unrestored@protected@xdef\@thefnmark{\thempfn}%
    \endgroup
  }{%
    \stepcounter\@mpfn
    \protected@xdef\@thefnmark{\thempfn}%
  }%
  \@footnotemark
  \ExpandArgs{no}\AddToHookNext{env/shaded/after}{%
    \expanded{%
      \smuggle@macro@in@e\@thefnmark
      \ifdefined\Hy@footnote@currentHref
        \smuggle@macro@in@e\Hy@footnote@currentHref
      \fi
    }%
    \@footnotetext{#2}%
  }%
}

% inserting to hooks `cmd/MakeFrame/before` and `cmd/endMakeFrame/after` would
% be more general, since `framed` package provides mupliple similar envs
\AddToHook{env/shaded/begin}{%
  \let\footnote=\footnote@in@shaded
}

\newcommand\smuggle@macro@in@e[1]{%
  \def\noexpand#1{\unexpanded\expandafter{#1}}%
}
\newcommand\myfootnotesep{\textsuperscript{,}}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\def\ShadedExample#1{%
  text\footnote{#1}\myfootnotesep\footnote{#1}
  \begin{shaded}
    shaded content%
    \footnote{inside shaded}\myfootnotesep
    \footnote[26]{inside shaded}\myfootnotesep
    \footnote{inside shaded}
  \end{shaded}
  text\footnote{#1}\myfootnotesep\footnote{#1}
}

\ShadedExample{outer}

\bigskip
\begin{minipage}{\linewidth}\sffamily
  \ShadedExample{inside minipage}
\end{minipage}

\bigskip
\ShadedExample{outer}

\newpage
abc
\end{document}
```

[image: main output]
[image: page footnote]

**Update** extending to all `framed` environments

```tex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage{framed}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage[colorlinks]{hyperref}

\colorlet{shadecolor}{gray!40}

\makeatletter
\NewDocumentCommand \footnote@in@shaded { o m }{%
  \IfValueTF{#1}{%
    \begingroup
      \csname c@\@mpfn\endcsname #1\relax
      \unrestored@protected@xdef\@thefnmark{\thempfn}%
    \endgroup
  }{%
    \stepcounter\@mpfn
    \protected@xdef\@thefnmark{\thempfn}%
  }%
  \@footnotemark
  \ExpandArgs{no}\AddToHookNext{env/shaded/after}{%
    \expanded{%
      \smuggle@macro@in@e\@thefnmark
      \ifdefined\Hy@footnote@currentHref
        \smuggle@macro@in@e\Hy@footnote@currentHref
      \fi
    }%
    \@footnotetext{#2}%
  }%
}

% Adding to hooks `cmd/MakeFramed/before` and `cmd/endMakeFramed/after` would
% be more general, since `framed` package provides mupliple similar envs.
% Will `\MakeFrame` and `\endMakeFrame` nest?
\AddToHook{cmd/MakeFramed/before}{%
  \let\footnote=\footnote@in@shaded
}

\newcommand\smuggle@macro@in@e[1]{%
  \def\noexpand#1{\unexpanded\expandafter{#1}}%
}
\newcommand\myfootnotesep{\textsuperscript{,}}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\def\FramedEnvExample#1#2{%
  text\footnote{#2}\myfootnotesep\footnote{#2}
  \begin{#1}
    #1 content%
    \footnote{inside #1}\myfootnotesep
    \footnote[26]{inside #1}\myfootnotesep
    \footnote{inside #1}
  \end{#1}
%  text\footnote{#2}\myfootnotesep\footnote{#2}
}

\FramedEnvExample{shaded}{outer}

\bigskip
\begin{minipage}{\linewidth}\sffamily
  \FramedEnvExample{shaded}{inside minipage}
\end{minipage}

\bigskip
\FramedEnvExample{framed}{outer}

\bigskip
\begin{minipage}{\linewidth}\sffamily
  \FramedEnvExample{framed}{inside minipage}
\end{minipage}

\newpage
abc
\end{document}
```

[image: shaded and framed envs]
[image: corresponding page footnote]

Comment: Wow. I believe this is one of the best suggestion `+1`